# Migrate G Suite to two separate G Suites

Tags: gmail, google-apps, google-workspace

I have one G Suite account with three domains (mainly many emails).

Now I would like to separate one domain to other fresh G Suite account. Of course with historical emails.

Anybody know how to do this? It's possible without G Suite support team?

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways of doing this and yes, you can do it yourself. Please consider that it can be tricky depending on the amount of data you want to move.

The main steps are:

- Create a new account with a temporary domain (the same domain can not be in two consoles at the same time)
- Migrate all the contents from your current account to the new one. You have different options to do this. The cheapest one is the [Data Migration Service](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6003169?hl=en) (DMS) that will only allow you to migrate only email using the IMAP protocol (so you need to know the users' passwords). Google support for the DMS is best effort, so if you have time and budget I recommend to use a commercial tool (my tool of choice here is [Cloud Migrator](https://cloudm.co/cloudmigrator)) that is also able to migrate calendar items and Google Drive files using the Google APIs (so it is transparent for the users).
- In a cut-off date that you agree with your users you remove the domain from the original console, you add it to the new one and perform a mass rename (my tool of choice here is [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM)).

There are many variables that can make the process much more complex that are difficult to describe in a single answer and this kind of activities usually require a dedicated project and a (small) team: I really suggest you to get some help.

Answer (score 0):

A word of warning:

I did this on Bluehost (transferring G Suite ownership of a domain from one Bluehost account to another) through Bluehost customer support.

It took 3 separate calls to Bluehost to get everything fully moved over. Make sure that your hosting provider sends you an email confirmation that everything happened successfully, because as a reseller of a Google product, they may not have complete authority over transferring ownership of Google's product.

Best regards.

Answer (score -1):

Also in reference to the domain go to Google Domain and you can see all the options you have in reference to your domain website etc. It is very self-explanatory.

wc.

Comment: welcome to stack-overflow please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and https://stackoverflow.com/tour for give best feedback here. wish you for the best